# Powershell removing spaces, adding commas after each field

Tags: powershell, parsing

I have a text file containing multiple spaces in between words on multiple lines. I am trying to remove the spaces and add a separator such as a comma to break each word apart. I then need to grab a specific index in a line.

I cannot figure out how to remove the spaces AND add a comma between each word.

Here is my current code:

```
$file_data_one = Get-Content Text1.txt
foreach ($line in $file_data_one) {
    Write-Output($line -replace(" ",""))
}
```

Comment: Try `$line -replace ' +',','` and that will replace all consecutive spaces with a single comma.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thank you so much! now that the values are separated, would you happen to know how to access a specific index on a line?

Comment: You can use `-split '\s+'` to get all the words in a string array and use your index on that

Comment: Yeah, what @Theo said, you'll need to split the text to get indexes. So, either split it instead of replacing spaces with commas, or do the replace and split on commas. `($Line -split '\s+')[8]` will get you the 9th word (because arrays are 0 based).